# Chrome Extension: Remembering a checkbox value when popup is reopened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, state

Newbie here so sorry if this is pretty elementary. I'm making an extension that simply has a checkbox/switch when loaded. It is to be unchecked the first time you open it but when the extension is closed and reopened, I would like it to display whether it was checked or not.

The checkbox starts a timer in the background.js and unchecking it stops it. I have all this working, except to save the state of the checkbox

Relevant HTML for the popup

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
            <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="notification" />
            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="notification">
                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Relevant part of popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.getElementById("notification").addEventListener('click', runTimer);
    console.log("DOM Loaded");
});

function runTimer() {...
```

In the html, my checkbox is set to unchecked. I was toying around with putting this into the popup.js

```
var switchState = document.getElementById("notification").checked;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        'value' : switchState
    }, function () {
        console.log("Switch Saved as " + switchState);
    });
```

I figure that would save the checkbox value so I could use it if I closed and reopened the extension. My issue is though that when I open the extension, the html takes over and creates the checkbox from scratch, unchecked.

How do I override this if I know that the extension has been opened once before and so I should now use the checkbox value from when I last had it open?

Comment: In your popup JavaScript, within your `DOMContentLoaded` event handler, you set the checkbox state to be the stored state. If using, `chrome.storage`, you will need to read the current state of your stored data. There are many examples floating around, including the one from [Google about an options page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2), which can trivially become a popup by just including it as the `default_popup`.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the code from [Google's options example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2) and transforming it to fit your code:

```
// Restores checkbox state using the preferences stored in chrome.storage.sync
function restoreOptions() {
    // Use default value = false.
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        value: false
    }, function (items) {
        document.getElementById('notification').checked = items.value;
    });
}
```

Then your `DOMContentLoaded` handler becomes:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    restoreOptions();
    document.getElementById("notification").addEventListener('click', runTimer);
    console.log("DOM Loaded");
});
```

Note that the use of `chrome.storage.sync` will store the state of the checkbox across not only different runs of Chrome on your machine, but all those which sync with that person. You may desire to use `chrome.storage.local` to limit storage of the checkbox state to that machine. In addition, you may desire to clear the state when the extension first runs when Chrome is started.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to add a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), that holds the state of the checkbox in a variable.

[Storing a variable](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted my previous response because I see where I went wrong again, code I used is below

```
function restoreOptions() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        //False is the default value when first opening the extension
        'initialValue' : false
    }, function (items) {
        document.getElementById('notification').checked = items.initialValue;
    });
}
```

Pretty much exactly what was suggested, as well as what was in the google options page (I did read it but just didn't get it at the time). I missed the bit where the 'initialValue' was set to false if storage didn't have a value which fixed my issue for when I launched the extension for the first time.

It's all prefectly clear now, finally. Thanks again for your help