# Chrome extension: Modifying the content of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a simple Chrome Extension where I will 'block' the content of the website Reddit by replacing it with a short text. This is what I have so far:

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "BlockIt",
"description": "Block Reddit, increase productivity!",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_title": "BlockIt"
},

"permissions": [
  "storage", "tabs",
  "http://www.reddit.com/*"
],

"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "*://reddit.com/*" ],
    "js": ["content-script.js"]
  }
] 
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        background-color:#EFF7FF;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        width: 110px;
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
      }
    </style>
    <!--Scripts-->
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>BlockIt!</h2>
    <div id="en"><label for="enable">Enable BlockIt</label> <input id="enable" type="checkbox" style="vertical-align:middle; position:relative; bottom: 1px;"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('#enable').addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
});

function changeHandler() {
    if (enable.checked) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'enable': true }, function () { });
    }
}
```

**content-script.js**

```
var content = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var text = "BlockIt enabled (to disable, click on the icon).";
//TODO: replace content with text
```

I'm having two major issues right now: I'm not sure how I should go about in modifying the content of the webpage and replace it with the `text` above, and I'm not sure how to inject `content-script.js` when the checkbox in `popup.html` is checked. How do I go about in approaching this?

**Edit**: I've made the following change to my code:

**content-script.js**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get({ enable: false }, items=> {
    if (items.enable) {
        document.body.textContent = "BlockIt enabled (to disable, click on the icon).";
    }
});
```

It successfully changes the body of the webpage, but the issue now is that the content of `popup.html` changes to the same text as well. What seems to be the problem?

**Edit 2**:
I've removed `content-scrip.js` in `popup.html`. The state of the checkbox still doesn't persist. It seems like such a simple solution but I can't seem to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That is really two distinct questions.  For the first, we need to know what you are wanting to replace. Are you wanting to replace the entire `<body>` (e.g. `document.body.textcontent=text;`), the entire `<document>`, etc.? It might be easier to block `webRequests` to `redit.com`.

Comment: @Makyen I would like to replace the enter `body` . Is it possible to display a custom message when blocking `webRequests`?

Comment: Yes, you could display a custom message from blocking a `webRequest`.  However, the way you would do so is different. You can redirect the request to a HTML file within your extension which would have the blocking message.

Comment: Arg... There is a typo in my first comment. It should have said `document.body.textContent=text;` (note the capital `C` in `textContent`).

Comment: FYI: From Stack Overflow's point of view, both your recent edits should be [new Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (you can have a link in a new question back to this one for context). Also, nobody is notified when you make an edit to your question. If you want to inform specific people, you will need to put a comment on a Question or Answer they wrote, or add a comment that includes their username preceded by an `@` (e.g. `@Makyen`, for me). You can only specify one person via `@`/comment, but the original poster of the Question/Answer on which you comment is always notified.

Comment: As to your most recent edit, if posted as a new Question, it would be closed as a duplicate. Your issue is not that the user's selection is not remembered from one time of opening your panel to the next, it is that you are not reading the stored information and updating the DOM to reflect the state of the checkbox. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40367226/3773011) answers a question from another user with an identical issue. You will need to change the DOM ID used, and the key used in the `storage.sync.get`. If you still have an issue, please leave a comment with `@Makyen`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use [`chrome.storage.sync.get()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) to get the enabled status at the time the *content-script.j* is injected into the page:

*content-script.js*:

```css
chrome.storage.sync.get({enable:false}, items=> {
    if(items.enable) {
        document.body.textContent="BlockIt enabled (to disable, click on the icon).";
    }
});
```

This is not reversible for the current page. Given that your users will probably expect the block to be reversible without having to reload the page, you might want to consider a different method of accomplishing your block than to replace all of the content.

In addition, this will only replace the `<body>` for pages which are loaded after the block is enabled. It will not affect pages which are already loaded. You will probably want to use [`chrome.tabs.query()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to get a list of tabs which are currently showing `reddit.com`. You will then need to inject the script again using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

Something like:

```js
//This requires the "tabs" permission.
//Execute after you have stored the data to chrome.storage.sync (e.g. in the callback)
chrome.tabs.query({url:"*://reddit.com/*"},tabs=>{
    tabs.forEach(tab=>{
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:"content-script.js"});
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Just making sure, is `=>` supposed to be part of the name of the function?

Comment: No, `items=>{}` is a shorter way to write `function(items) {}`. They are called [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). They are a new thing in JavaScript which was introduced in ES6. You should not, yet, use them for general JavaScript programming because the syntax is not supported by all browsers. However, for a Chrome extension we know that it will be running on Chrome, which does support the syntax. I used it because it is faster to write. I can change the answer to using `function(...){...}` if you would prefer.

Comment: that's fine, you don't have to change the answer since you explained to me what it was. Thanks again :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. If you have any issues with actually putting this in your code, feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: @coriandres, I'm not sure why you using any of the methods in that answer. From what you have described in your question as what you desire, and the code you have shown, there is no need to use any of those methods. Given the *manifest.json* you have in your question you are already injecting your content script into the page. The methods in that answer are only if you need to interact directly with the scripts that are already running on the webpage, which you don't need to do.  You may need to disable such scripts by changing the `<head>` of the `document`, but not using those methods.

Comment: @coriandres, That problem is caused by having the line `<script src="content-script.js"></script>` in your *popup.html*. It should not be there. Remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be much more resource-efficient to block using [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) request redirection.

Let's say you have a page `blocked.html` that is shown in place of content.

Then, again, suppose that the extension state is stored in `chrome.storage.sync`, as in Mayken's answer. You'll need a synchronous cache of the value, because redirect must be synchronous.

```
// Background script
var enabled;

function cacheEnabled() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({enable: false}, data => {
    enabled = data.enable;
  });
}

cacheEnabled();
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(cacheEnabled);

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  details => {
    if (enabled) {
      return { redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL("blocked.html") };
    }
  },
  {
    urls: ["*://*.reddit.com/*"],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
  },
  ["blocking"]
);
```

This requires permissions `"webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://*.reddit.com/*"`.

Note: This is not an optimal solution: it's even better to register/unregister the listener depending on `enabled` rather than check it inside the listener (which should be as fast as possible). This is left as an exercise.